# How the certificate signing request (CSR) is signed?

Tags: security, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, pki

I am trying to understand how the CSR get signed by the certificate authority. I want to understand in detail what exactly meant by signing the csr ? will it create some hash of the certificate?

Comment: Multiple duplicates in security.se. eg: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234365/help-understanding-csr-fields/234367#234367

Comment: The easiest answer is "the CA never signs the CSR". They read data from it and then make a certificate that only has to have the public key in common with the request... everything else is just a suggestion/request.

Comment: Bartonjs with all due respect that is not a helpful response and very misleading as written.